# How to load a UIView from a certain frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I want to load a view from a certain place within my current view. Currently, my view consists of a calendar with day buttons, each representing a day within the month. One of the buttons is highlighted to represent the "today" button. I want to load my view from that position and grow that view from that small frame.
More specifically, I want to load `yearCalendarView` from the frame of a button inside `curMonthView`. Here is what I have currently:

[image]

```
// animate in year calendar
    _yearCalendarView.hidden = NO;
    self.curMonthView.monthLabel.hidden = YES;

    CalendarMonthView *monthView = [CalendarMonthView new];
    monthView.delegate = self;
    CGRect buttonFrame = _currentDayButtonFrame;

    _yearCalendarView.frame = buttonFrame;
    _yearCalendarView.center = buttonFrame.origin;
    _yearCalendarView.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateYearCalendarIn" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];  // kAnimation_AnimateInDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
    _yearCalendarView.alpha = 1.0;
    _yearCalendarView.frame = CGRectMake(_monthSwiperScrollView.frame.origin.x, _monthBarImageView.frame.size.height + 20, _monthSwiperScrollView.frame.size.width + 2, _yearFlyoutHeight);
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector (yearCalendarAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];

    [_yearCalendarView setFrameHeight:_yearFlyoutHeight];

    [UIView commitAnimations];  // start animation
    _monthBarImageView.highlighted = YES;
    [self _refreshMonthButton:NO];
```

I have the frame of the today button, but when I do this animation, it does not grow from that frame rather it just comes in from the bottom left corner of the new view `_yearCalendarView`.

How do I achieve this effect?

TLDR: Load a view from a known frame and then grow that frame to fit the screen.

Comment: Can you explain more, which view you want to do animate?, from frame? to fram?

Comment: Check edited Question. I want to load `_yearCalendarView` from the frame of the today button within the `curMonthView` view.

Comment: So what the problem do you have?" just comes in from the bottom left corner of the new view"?. _yearView grow is ok, but wrong in start point. Or it doesn't grow. Or frame is wrong, or ...

Comment: The problem is is that the view does not load from the todayButton frame, it just grows from the top of the view and then comes down then goes diagnal. I want it to grow from that frame that I have not shift.

Comment: _yearCalendarView, _monthSwiperScrollView, buttonFrame have the same superview? Can you print out the value of `_yearCalendarView.frame = buttonFrame;`, `_yearCalendarView.center = buttonFrame.origin;`, `_yearCalendarView.frame = CGRectMake(_monthSwiperScrollView.frame.origin.x, _monthBarImageView.frame.size.height + 20, _monthSwiperScrollView.frame.size.width + 2, _yearFlyoutHeight);
    `

Comment: The frame of _yearCalendarView animate from A to B. check A, B carefully. And care about superview of _yearCalendarView, and others. If they aren't on the same superview, you have convert the frame.

Comment: ignore the final frame dimensions because that is not that important, but the view starts out as the month view and then the year view is loaded on top of that. I will upload a gif showing this

Comment: So you want the _year starts from the  frame of the "9". Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89211/discussion-between-anhtu-and-varun-varahabotla).